# javascript variables not being passed

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the variables current and at do not pass to the function but when I sue the console the correct value comes up?  I am completely clueless on this one which means it must be simple!

```
records = [118571, 118666, 118693, 118791, 118827, 118942, 119041, 119144, 119265, 119310, 119430, 119570, 119617, 119726, 119762, 120030, 120086, 120103, 120129, 120145, 120219, 120365, 120441, 120562, 120607, 120932, 121072, 121232, 121260, 121667, 121725, 121764, 121876, 122007, 122008, 122009, 122131, 122458, 122804, 123081, 123156, 123239, 123320, 123413, 123624, 123715, 123842, 123953];
x = 48;
y = 48;
current = 123953;
function changerecord(change) {

    var at = records.indexOf(current);

    if (change == -1) {
        var next = current;//current because we are going back one
        var previous = records[at - 3];//-2 because we started on record and are moving 2 back
        var moveto = records[at - 2];
        x = x - 1;
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = x + ' of ' + y;
        alert("AT : " + at + "\n" + "Previous : " + previous + "\n" + "Next : " + next + "\n" + "x : " + x + "\n" + "y : " + y + "\n" + "moveto : " + moveto + "\n");
        var current = moveto;
        //document.getElementById('iframe_records').src='recordtemplate.php?flight=' + moveto;
    }
    else if (change == +1) {
        var previous = current;//current because we are going back one
        var next = records[at + 2];//-2 because we started on record and are moving 2 back
        var moveto = records[at + 1];
        x = x + 1;
        alert("AT : " + at + "\n" + "Previous : " + previous + "\n" + "Next : " + next + "\n" + "x : " + x + "\n" + "y : " + y + "\n" + "moveto : " + moveto + "\n");
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = x + ' of ' + y;
        var current = moveto;
        //document.getElementById('iframe_records').src='recordtemplate.php?flight=' + moveto;
    }
}; // lookup
```

Comment: where are you calling the function?

Comment: Please notice the following line of code(written twice) in the function:
var current=moveto;
It is causing the problem. As I am not good at explaining, please check the following uri: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting
Hoisting is (to many developers) an unknown or overlooked behavior of JavaScript.

Comment: xD. Learner has your solution. The Hoisting concept will recover all the variable in your Function and will declare it At the begining of the function (or bracket) , so in your  else if (change==+1) , current will be current declare LOCAL !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some scoping and variable name problems in there:

First of, try to declare variables with `var`

```
var records = [...]
var variable = ...
```

so this is global in the current scope and you also can use it in the function, if the function is also in the scope.

You are just changing the value of `current` and than inside the function scope, you are using `var current = ..`. Use another name, it's not like they are limited.

```
var test = 1;

function test() {

    console.log(test); // Output: 1

    var test = 2;
    var oktopus = 8;

    console.log(test); // Output: 2
    console.log(oktopus); // Output: 8

}

console.log(test); // Output: 1
console.log(oktopus); // undefined oktopus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `current` as a parameters, to avoid this problem:
then when you call `changerecord`, it will be like this:

```
changerecord(change, 123953)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a value to the variable `current` without declaring it with `var` keyword. When you do such this, i.e. assign a value to a non-declared variable, that variable become a *property* on global object (i.e. window).

Another point that you should know is when you declare a local variable with the same name as another variable in parent function scope, the most localized variable will be used in the inner function scope.

```
// ...
current = 123953; // Global variable
function changerecord(change) { // Local variable

    var at = records.indexOf(current); // Local variable will be used

    if (change==-1) // Also local one
    {   
        var next = current; // Still local one!
// ...
```

Note that `window.current` should work.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changerecord(change);
});
```